# iTunes Connect - Can't edit app info, submit for review, release, etc

Tags: ios, app-store

I have the following roles: App Manager, Customer Support, Sales

That allows for:

- **Create Apps and Submit Versions**
- Upload Builds
- **Edit App Store Details**
- Manage Promo Codes and Promo Art
- Manage TestFlight Builds
- Manage TestFlight Testers
- Edit App Pricing and Availability
- Create In-App Purchases
- Submit In-App Purchases
- Edit In-App Purchases
- Manage Game Center
- Manage Leaderboard Scores
- View App Analytics
- View Sales and Trends (Sales Only)
- Reply to and Edit Responses to Customer Reviews

However, when I click onto one of my apps, it just takes me to a "Ratings and Reviews" page. There is no way for me to edit the app information or send it for review let alone release the app. All worked perfectly well before.

Is anyone else experiencing this issue? Has something changed on Apples side?

Comment: In "Users and Roles" what does it say underneath "Apps"?

Comment: I have access to "All Apps". As I say, I can see the apps and can see there is a new version as they are in the "Prepare for submission" state. Clicking them though just takes me to "Ratings and Reviews"

Comment: Nothing has changed; I logged into an account with the same permissions and it worked fine.

Comment: Strange, very strange. I have tried contacting Apple themselves but not sure how long I will be waiting for a response from them. It feels to me like its an issue their side.

Comment: Was your new version created using Xcode Beta or anything like that?

Comment: We use TeamCity with Fastlane to build and upload our apps to iTunes Connect. It's using Xcode 8.3.3. We've done this several times before however and had no issues.

Comment: Usually the developer support responds fairly quickly; hopefully they can tell you what the issue is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to get the `Customer Support` user role removed from my account (which I think Apple auto-added). Now I can access all the app meta data.

I still think this must be a bug Apple side as this is just a workaround. When/if I hear back from Apple, I will update this answer.

**Apples Response**

> We believe this issue has been resolved. If you are still encountering
>   that you are unable to edit app information or upload builds, please
>   send us a screenshot of the error and steps to reproduce the issue.

So not much help really. I'm not sure if the issue is actually resolved as I haven't requested to have the `Customer Support` role added to my account again.

Comment: The same to you!

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue, starting today.. when clicking on the app it takes me to the reviews for the app and no way to navigate to TestFlight..

If I manually change the url from:

https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/ng/app/{APP_ID_GOES_HERE}/ios/ratingsResponses

To: (NOTE: No trailing slash should be added to this url, if a trailing slash is added it will simply redirect to the iTunes connect homepage)

https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/ng/app/{APP_ID_GOES_HERE}

I am able to view TestFlight and continue as normal. This appears to be a UI navigational error and not a user permissions issue.

---

Disclaimer: I posted the same answer here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/84444